# Filtering columns in datatable

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a datatable with multiple columns. I want to filter the columns for which i do:

```
newDatableName= OldDt.ToTable(false,"col1","col2");
```

Now suppose, I want to specify the column names dyanamically i.e put all the column names in a string and then Do:

```
string colnames= "col1,col2";
 newDatableName= OldDt.ToTable(false,colnames);
```

I tried the above but it does not work. I even tried:

```
string colname= "\"col1\",\"col2\"";
```

but it considers the string of column names as one column and gives the error that no such column present.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose that you are using the [DataView.ToTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h2b6ehaa(v=vs.110).aspx) method (so OldDT is a DataView not a DataTable).
In this case you need to pass an array of your column names

```
string[] colnames = new string[] {"col1", "col2"};
newDatableName= OldDt.ToTable(false,colnames);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use Steve's answer, if don't like defining a new array try this:

```
string colnames="col1,col2"
newDatableName=OldDt.ToTable(colnames.Split(',');
```

Comment: @JacksonLopes anyway your end goal isn't clear, why do you want them to be in one string ?

Comment: Thanks Man. Your answer helped me a lot but since it was Steve who showed me the way, I had to mark his answer. Thanks a ton. Cheers !!!

Answer (score 0):

```
DataTable.DefaultView.ToTable(bool, Params string[] ColumnNames);
```

The above Method creates and returns a new `DataTable` based on rows in an existing `DataView`.

You have to passes two parameters to this function.
If true, the returned DataTable  contains rows that have distinct values for all its columns. The default value is false.
A string array that contains a list of the column names to be included in the returned DataTable . The `DataTable` contains the specified columns in the order they appear within this array.
**For Example:**

```
DataTable NewTable = dt.DefaultView.ToTable(false, "StartDate", "FinishDate", "ItemName", "AssigneeNames", "ProjectName", "PercentComplete");
```